# itextsharp C#: How to draw Diagonal Line inside Table Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, pdf, itext

How to draw a diagonal line inside inside the cell of a pdf table using itextsharp C#?
I want something like this: [Splitting table cells diagonally itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253087/splitting-table-cells-diagonally-itextsharp) but in C#. Because that post is with java, and I cannot do it in C#

Comment: Porting that Java code to C# is pretty straight forward. Thus, I wonder, is it really the porting that stops you, or is it actually the usage of the ported code?

Comment: Not really. It gives me a lot of errors: PdfPCellEvent that dosen't exist (in C#). I change it but I have other errors: "PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setCellEvent(new Diagonal("Gravity", "Occ"));" that also gives me error. cell dosen't have 'setCellEvent'. And canvas.moveTo(position.getLeft(), position.getTop());
        canvas.lineTo(position.getRight(), position.getBottom()); also dosen't work, since it waits to recive an int, not empty

Comment: Those are simple naming convention issues. *"PdfPCellEvent that dosen't exist (in C#)"* - in .Net (and, therefore, in iTextSharp) interface names commonly start with an **I**, so its `IPdfPCellEvent` there. *"cell dosen't have 'setCellEvent'"* - in .Net methods usually start with a capital letter. And instead of getter/setter method pairs you often see properties in .Net. In this case its a property, try `cell.CellEvent`. *"position.getLeft(), ..."* - again properties, use `position.Left`, ...

Comment: Thank you for your time (and patience). I made all the changes, but I still have problems with cell.CellEvent(new Diagonal("Gravity", "Occ")); -> ERROR: Cannot use non-callable member 'PdfPCell.CellEvent' as method. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: *"I still have problems with cell.CellEvent(new Diagonal("Gravity", "Occ"))"* - `cell.CellEvent` is a property which is treated like a member variable. Thus, you have to use `cell.CellEvent = new Diagonal("Gravity", "Occ")` in C#.

Comment: ok, now it works cell.CellEvent = new Diagonal("Gravity", "Occ");

Comment: Do you want to create an actual answer to your question yourself or shall i create one?

Comment: @Keras-JOB, It seems that you have solved your problem. Therefore, I make an answer for it so that it can help others who face the similar problem. You can consider accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mkl's suggestion in the comment, you can try to use the following code to draw a diagonal line in the table cell.

First, please install nuget-package `iTextSharp`.

Second, here is a completed code example you can refer to.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.createPdf("E:\\test.pdf");
        }


        public void createPdf(String dest)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(dest,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (Document document = new Document())
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                    document.Open();
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
                    table.DefaultCell.MinimumHeight=30;
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                    cell.CellEvent = new PdfPCellEvent("Gravity", "Occ");
                    //cell.setCellEvent(new Diagonal("Gravity", "Occ"));
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                    table.AddCell("1");
                    table.AddCell("2");
                    table.AddCell("3");
                    table.AddCell("4");
                    table.AddCell("5");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5;)
                    {
                        table.AddCell((++i).ToString());
                        table.AddCell("");
                        table.AddCell("");
                        table.AddCell("");
                        table.AddCell("");
                        table.AddCell("");
                    }
                    document.Add(table);
                    document.Close();
                    
                }
            }

        }



public class PdfPCellEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        protected String columns;
        protected String rows;

        public PdfPCellEvent(String columns, String rows)
        {
            this.columns = columns;
            this.rows = rows;
        }
        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
        {
            PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                new Phrase(columns), position.GetRight(2), position.GetTop(12), 0);
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                new Phrase(rows), position.GetLeft(2), position.GetBottom(2), 0);
            canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
            canvas.MoveTo(position.Left, position.Top);
            canvas.LineTo(position.Right, position.Bottom);
            canvas.Stroke();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]